# Did Microsoft push an update that returned case sensitivity to Access accdb's?

Tags: vba, ms-access

It appears that Microsoft has a recent patch that is making queries and filters in access accdb case sensitive, again.  Looks like this was changed to not case sensitive sometime between 2007 and 2016 roll-out.  Since I have converted all of my mdb's to accdb's I have not had issue until today. it seems now the case sensitivity is back. The below script has been working for at least a year up until yesterday.  example:

```
SELECT AllLibs.ActID, AllLibs.WBS, AllLibs.ActName, AllLibs.Start, AllLibs.Finish, AllLibs.WW, AllLibs.Cal, AllLibs.ODur, AllLibs.BudgLaborUnit AS ManHrs, AllLibs.ResID, AllLibs.WkCtrUpt, AllLibs.WkCtr, AllLibs.PMType, AllLibs.Unit, AllLibs.OSYS, AllLibs.Freq, AllLibs.Matrix, AllLibs.Risk, AllLibs.LCO, AllLibs.KeyWork
FROM AllLibs INNER JOIN RTNOSelector ON AllLibs.MaintItem = RTNOSelector.RTNO
ORDER BY AllLibs.Start;
```

This particular Join is fixed with a Ucase function on the RTNOSelector.RTNO since the base data in AllLibs.MaintItem is all caps.  How do I find data that is mixed case and has no standard format.  I cannot find an option to turn this case sensitivity on or off like in MS-Excel.

Comment: I started using Access with 2003 and AFAIK, has never been case sensitive by default. Forcing case sensitivity requires some effort. However, I stopped upgrading with Access 2010. Tested in Immediate window: `?"aBC" = "aBc"` returns True. So use of UCase() is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In code, the setting is:

```
Option Compare Database|Text|Binary
```

Queries, I guess, use the setting of the database.

To check for a match of case, use *StrComp*:

```
Match = (StrComp(String1, String2, vbBinaryCompare) = 0)
```